# Mediawiki - Script error: Lua error at line 1: unexpected symbol near '/'

Tags: css, lua, compiler-errors, mediawiki

I have to say I am unclear on the real reason for the error, but my only observation is that this `.css` file is being treated as a Lua file for whatever reason, which is why we see the error below.

[image]

`Module:Citation/CS1/styles.css`

http://www.gwart.co.uk/Module:Citation/CS1/styles.css

Other related errors: http://www.gwart.co.uk/Les_Edwards

How can I either fix this issue or alternatively, if needed, make this be a `file` rather than a `module`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the page is being parsed as Lua because the [content model](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Content_handlers) is "Scribunto". If the [TemplateStyles](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TemplateStyles) extension is installed, an admin can apparently [change the content model](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:ChangeContentModel) of the page from "Scribunto" to "sanitized-css" and the page will be parsed correctly.

Another approach if you are not an admin is to create a .css subpage in the Template namespace and then move it to the Module namespace. Creating it in the Template namespace automatically gives it the "sanitized-css" content model, and it keeps its content model when it is moved to the Module namespace.

There is a [Phabricator ticket](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T200914) requesting that Module subpages ending in .css automatically have the "sanitized-css" content model, but I do not know what progress has been made on implementing that.

Comment: I'll give you the correct answer for flagging the Change content model :) Thanks bud